# Как вывести текст даже если в нем есть """, ", ', Python

Tags: python

Так столкнулся с довольно странной проблемой. у меня есть текст очень большого кода в котором присутствуют такие символы как """, ", ' мне нужно вывести этот код через банальный print. логично что если ввести print("""тот самый код""") то он будет выдавать ошибку из за того что в том самом коде есть тройные кавычки

Answer (score 1):

Если ты считываешь .txt файл с помощью функции open(), то он считывается как последовательность байтов. Даже если там не код, а дичь полная, то отправляя этот текст в функцию print() ошибки возникнуть не может, ведь он его выводит, а не выполняет как repr().
(Не копируй код программы в переменную, считывай из файла)

```
with open('myText.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в тексте есть тройные кавычки только одного вида (одиночные либо двойные), то вообще нет проблем - начинаете и заканчиваете тройными кавычками другого вида. А вот если там есть и те и другие кавычки, то придётся тот вид кавычек, с которого вы начали, как-то экранировать знаком `\`:

```
print('''
Всякий ' разный " текст можно и такие кавычки '' 
и вот такие "" и тройные можно в принципе """,
только не те, с которых всё началось,
такие придётся экранировать так ''\' или так '\''
''')
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Всякий ' разный " текст можно и такие кавычки '' 
> и вот такие "" и тройные можно в принципе """,
> только не те, с которых всё началось,
> такие придётся экранировать так ''' или так '''
> ```